# How to remove scrollbar and allow scroll?

Tags: css

I've tried almost everything I've seen but it still does not work. How would I remove the scrollbar but be able to scroll?

```css
<head>
<style>

body{
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 font-smooth: never;
 -webkit-font-smoothing : none;
 text-shadow: none;
 word-wrap: break-word;
 padding: 0;
 line-height:12.000000*1.1px;
 font-size:12.000000px;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-color:#FFFFFF;
 font-weight: bold;
 width:90%;
 height:90%;
 }
</style>

</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, technically. However, you can style all the scrollbar components to be effectively invisible for the body:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{background-color:#fff;color:#fff;width:0;height:0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button{background-color:#fff;color:#fff;width:0;height:0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{background-color:#fff;color:#fff;width:0;height:0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece{background-color:#fff;color:#fff;width:0;height:0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color:#fff;color:#fff;width:0;height:0}
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner{background-color:#fff;color:#fff;width:0;height:0}
::-webkit-resizer{background-color:#fff;color:#fff;width:0;height:0}}
```

This will work across webkit browsers.

Comment: Is there a reason to not just say `body::-webkit-scrollbar { display:none; } `?

Comment: Looks like that works in Chrome now - interesting. I know older versions of webkit didn't respect a display: none on scrollbar selectors. This would be the most cross-browser compatible method.